# Value Checkbox Inside modal

Tags: php, jquery

i'm trying to do a system to check if the member attended to the meeting.

I will check it using his ID, so, i a form to input his ID(it will be read by a bar code reader that the id will be the bar code, everything will be in a card), but if the member forget his card, should have another way to find his ID, so i'm using a modal open a form, so can find his name and pass his ID to the form.

On the modal, i'm using ajax to get dinamically his name (and his id on a checkbox), it works properly, but i cant take the checkbox value and pass it into the ID FORM.

Thats my code.

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="attendedForm" name="formPresenca">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <span>ID</span>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="alvo" />
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
            <a href="#" id="popup"  rel="">Seach Manually</a>                </fieldset>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
   $(function(){
       $("a#popup").click(function(){
           $.modal('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><fieldset><label><span>Name</span><input type="text" name="Name" id="id" /></label></fieldset><div id="recebe_dados"></div></form>', {
               overlayId: 'contact-overlay'
           });
           $("#id").on('keyup', function(){
               var nome = $(this).val();
               $.post("../scripts/get-name.php",
                   {name:name},
                   function(value){
                       $("#get_data").html(value);
                   });

//Dont shows me anything on the console.
                       $("#Checkbox").click(function(){
                           console.log($('#Checkbox:checked').val());
                       });
           });

            });
       });
```

Get-value.php

```
$get = $_POST['nome'];
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%$get%'");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="'.$res['id'].'" id="Checkbox">'.$res['nome'];

}
```

I'm using Simple modal.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: A guess: the dom element does not exist when you try to access them because you generate them dynamically.
You should either use a callback if available or use another method which JQuery provides which is to have the modal popup hidden already in your page and just show it.

Check the $("#Checkbox") value to be sure.

Comment: Is this a typo: $get = $_POST['nome'];?? Perhaps should be 'name'? OR perhaps you ajax param should read: {nome:nome}

Comment: @StaticVoid i translated to english, but i forgett this part, sorry.

Comment: @DanielA.White i know, but it will not runs Online, but i need to learn how to counter sql injection.

Comment: `while(..)` duplicate IDs `#checkbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your while loop could possibly create duplicate IDs -- invalid HTML -- use the following instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Checkbox", function(){
     console.log( this.value );
});
```

And:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="'.$res['id'].'" class="Checkbox">'.$res['nome'];
```

And, this should be outside the `keyup` callback but inside `DOM ready`.